# Can we use encrypted fields in Report Filters with Platform Encryption

Tags: reporting, encryption, platform-encryption

I have a use case where few fields on objects have to be encrypted, but there should be a provision to use these fields in filter criteria while creating records.

But by seeing restrictions on these reference docs https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm

there is no way to use encrypted fields in filter criteria on reports
.But seems to be in new release there is some new feature 'Platform Encryption' which can help to  Encrypt Sensitive Data while Preserving Platform Functionality . But i was wondering will this provide the feature to use the encrypted fields to be used in report filtering too.

I have went through many docs for getting this, but haven't found much.To test this  platform encryption currently it is not available in my client environment, and it was mentioned we need  some extra licence for this.

Before proceeding i was just looking does this allow encrypted fields in filters too...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no.

Per this doc:

**Considerations for Using Platform Encryption With Fields**

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_pe_considerations_all_fields.htm&language=en_US

> Encrypted fields can’t be used in:
>
> - Criteria-based sharing rules
> - Filter criteria for list views, reports, and dashboards
> - Portals: communities, customer, self-service, and partner
> - Similar opportunities searches External lookup relationships

And the doc is discussing both Platform Encryption AND Standard Encrypted fields so "Encrypted Fields" above refers to both.

Comment: thanks eric... i do think the same, is there any better  approach to over come this eric

Comment: @rajasekhar - Not that I am aware of if you need to keep the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption has to be enabled by SF. Encrypted text fields formerly had a max length of 175 characters. Permission required: View Encrypted Data. Encrypted Fields can be searched, cannot be unique, cannot be external ID, and cannot have a default value. Since they can be searched, I'd expect you could use them as a filter in a search.

They can be included in reports, I but can't say about whether they can be filtered in a report. Most anything that you can include in a report can be filtered, but as I've not tested reporting on encrypted fields, I wouldn't want to say for certain.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Provided information is very helpful. I feel there is minor correction max length for encrypted fields is not limited to 175 characters. I could go to its full capacity as 255.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar I suggest you double check the documentation. I just looked and according to https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm&language=th, the limit is still 175 characters. If you've found a different limit someplace else, please cite the reference.

Comment: Consider this ref: http://imgur.com/sumCZzi

Comment: @KiranMachhewar Are you using the Salesforce Shield product? If so, that's not standard encryption. Please provide a link to current documentation.